# How to create a report that groups a selection of fields by the day of the week

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports and have been asked to produce a report that is sectioned off by Day of the Week (Monday, Tuesday, ...), has a required data range, then lists all activities for the day of the week within that date range.

I tried to insert an image but I am told I can't so ....

The first line of each section should be gray in color and have the column headers for the start date, start time, end time, event, day of the week (ie: MONDAY), location of event.  Under that 'header' line there should be a list of all events with in the date range that fall on a MONDAY.  The next section would be TUESDAY, the next WEDNESDAY....and so on.

I have tried putting the 'header' in the detail section but it repeated (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue,...).  So I tried inserting a group header above the detail section.  `Group Header # 1` worked ok...it had detail a below it but I can't figure out how to get the second group header to be directly before detail b section for Tuesday.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: Check the name of the weekday name and use accordingly
```

Assuming your database field is `date`

Create a Formula `@Group` and use that formula in `grouping`

```
if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Monday"
Then "Monday"
Else if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Tuesday"
Then "Tuesday"
Else if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Wednesday"
Then "Wednesday"
Else if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Thursday"
Then "Thursday"
Else if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Friday"
Then "Friday"
Else if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Saturday"
Then "Saturday"
Else if WeekdayName (DayOfWeek ({databasefield.Date})) ="Sunday"
Then "Sunday"
```

Use the created formula `@Group` in grouping so that you will get all the groups one by one

Now in details keep the `Events` database field